# How to do? Click on accordion item -> scroll to top of active one

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I've created an accordion that can currently only open one panel at a time. However, I cannot get it to scroll to the active accordion of a panel when I click it.

How should I modify my code to clicking on the accordion jumps to the top of the page view?

This is my code:

```js
// Select all accordion items
var acc = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');

// Iterate to add event listeners
acc.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // When it's clicked, loop through all the items
        acc.forEach(el => {
            // Close any open items
            if (el.classList.contains('active')) {
                closeAcc(el);
                // If it's the one that was clicked and it's closed, open it
            } else if (el === item) {
                openAcc(el);
            }
        });
    });
});

function closeAcc (el) {
    el.classList.remove('active');
    el.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
};

function openAcc (el) {
    el.classList.add('active');
    el.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = el.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color:lightseagreen;
  color: black;
}
.active{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position:sticky;
}
.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color:white;
  color: black;
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">TITLE 1</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>details</p>
  </div>
<button class="accordion">TITLE 2</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>details</p>
  </div>
<button class="accordion">TITLE 3</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>details</p>
  </div>
```

Sample text because my post is mosty code...

Comment: This is lacking any of your CSS, so we can't even see whether you implemented any transitions, or how exactly it behaves. Please provide a proper [mre], when you ask this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

  panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Scroll nach oben
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth" // Optional: Fügt Scroll-Animation hinzu
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tank you @crafter32, I just copied it after my original script and unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: tried to change the event listener? Or did you try to write something in the console to know if the code is even triggered or not? Just tried it out with changed eventlistener and it seems to work